# Realloc in a for loop

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function which should return all arguments as a concatenated char array. Unfortunately, I get an 'invalid pointer' error while using the function. I'm new to C so maybe I'm wrong in using realloc in this way.

```
char* concat(int argc, ...) {
    char* result;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, argc);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        char* s = va_arg(args, char*);
        int length = (result) ? strlen(result) : 1;

        char* tmp = (char*)realloc(result, sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + length - 1));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            throw_error("Realloc failed in `concat`.");
        }

        result = tmp;
        memcpy(&(result[length-1]), s, strlen(s));

        printf("result: %s\n", s);
    }

    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

The error message if it can help:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./pascc: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006060c8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76bb6)[0x7f9953be8bb6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x338)[0x7f9953beed58]
./pascc[0x401368]
./pascc[0x400f85]
./pascc[0x4019bb]
./pascc[0x403c49]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xff)[0x7f9953b90eff]
./pascc[0x400e29]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2885504
```

To avoid memory leak, I read in an other thread that I shouldn't realloc something itself like this:

```
result = (char*)realloc(result, sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + length - 1));
```

So I'm trying to find the good way to do this. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: gcc with options `-Wall -O3` tells me that "result may be used uninitialized in this function". And I am sure that valgrind also would tell you something like "conditional depends on uninitialized value in...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are `realloc`ing an uninitialized pointer.

```
char* result;
```

To use `realloc` you must either use a NULL pointer or a pointer that points to memory that was assigned by `malloc`.

```
char* result = NULL;
```

Comment: Good catch, `result` is uninitialized. This line is probably causing a problem first though: `int length = (result) ? strlen(result) : 1;`

Comment: +1. Also, `(strlen(s) + length - 1)` should be `(strlen(s) + length + 1)`. `strlen` does *not* include the terminal null byte -- for example, `strlen("a")` is `1` -- so he needs `+1` to allocate space for it.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't tested that part yet.

Comment: Using a NULL pointer results in a segmentation fault over here.

Answer (score 3):

Why not determine the required size then perform one malloc?

Something like this (caveat, I'm just typing in this answer, I don't have a c compiler handy):

```
char* concat(int argumentCount, ...)
{
  char* arguments[argumentcount];  // not sure this works in C.
  int index;
  char* result;
  size_t totalSize = 1;

  va_list argumentVector;
  va_start(argumentVector, argumentCount);

  for (index = 0; index < argumentCount; ++index)
  {
     arguments[index] = va_arg(argumentVector, char*);

     totalSize += strlen(arguments[index]);
  }

  va_end(argumentVector);

  result = calloc(totalSize, sizeof(char));

  for (index = 0; index < argumentCount; ++index)
  {
    strcat(result, arguments[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good option that I thought of. I will test to see which one is the more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkByers is right, but I'd make some more changes.  I'd:

1. change `char *result;` to `char *result = NULL;`.
2. change `int length = (result) ? strlen(result) : 1;` to `int length = (result) ? strlen(result) : 0;`.
3. change `char* tmp = (char*)realloc(result, sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + length - 1));` to `char* tmp = (char*)realloc(result, sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + length + 1));`.
4. change `memcpy(&(result[length-1]), s, strlen(s));` to `strcpy(result + length, s);`.
5. add `free(result);` before calling `throw_error` assuming that that exits the function (as throwing an exception would in C++).

Reasons:

1. Ensures that `result` is initialized so that the `realloc` call won't do something strange like try to extend or `free` random memory.
2. Ensures that `length` always gives the current `strlen` of the string stored in `result`.
3. Allocates enough space to store the original `length` characters in `result`, the new `strlen(s)` characters in `s`, and the terminating `NULL` byte.
4. Copies the string (even including the terminating `NULL` byte) without having to compute `strlen(s)` again.  We just need to skip the `length` string characters that were already stored.
5. Ensures that a problem with the `realloc` call won't leak the already-allocated memory.

Comment: An alternative to `strcpy(result + length, s)` is `memcpy(result + length, s, strlen(s) + 1)`.